# Upper bound for sum of powers of 2 from 1 to $\log n$ where powers are multiplied by 2 each time?

Tags: number-theory, power-series, exponential-sum

> Upper bound for sum of powers of 2 from 1 to $\log n$ where powers are multiplied by 2 each time?

I'm trying to find the upper bound for the following series

$$s(n) = 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^4 + 2^8 + 2^{16} + 2^{32} + \dots + 2^{\log n}.$$

From the series, it is clear that the exponent of the $i$th term is obtained by multiplying the exponent of the $(i-1)$th term exponent.

It is clear that the series is not a Geometric Progression. Can someone suggest any other hints to solve the sequence?

Comment: Known that for $r \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ that $$1 + 2 + 2^2 + \cdots + 2^r = 2^{(r+1)} - 1.$$  Consider $r$ to be the smallest positive integer $\geq \log(n)$.  Unclear to me whether an elegant tighter upper bound can be expressed, in terms of $n$.

Comment: Re last comment, unclear if this is appropriate: $$2^{(r+1)} - 1 + 2^{\log(n)} - 2^r.$$